# Trouble with vlcj to play Video

Tags: vlcj

As part of a project for college, i have to be able to play video in my java app.

I've written the following code:

```
EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent component = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent();

JFrame f = new JFrame ();

f.setContentPane(component);

f.setBounds(new Rectangle (200,200,800,600));

f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

    public void windowClosing (WindowEvent e) {

    component.release();

    System.exit(0);

    }

});

f.setVisible(true);

component.mediaPlayer().media().play("video");
```

Everything compiles successfully and when i run the project, the window for the video opens, i can hear the sound of the video but no image is shown. Can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: Which platform are you running on? macOS?

Comment: yes i'm running on macOS @caprica

Answer (score 0):

The `EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent` needs an AWT `Canvas` to embed the video.

When running on macOS there is no heavyweight AWT so a normal embedded media player component will not work.

You need instead to use some form of "direct rendering" where you paint the video yourself into some lightweight component. vlcj provides an implementation of this with the `CallbackMediaPlayerComponent`

To get the basics working, you can simply replace your code:

```
EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent component = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent();
```

With:

```
CallbackMediaPlayerComponent component = new CallbackMediaPlayerComponent();
```

This will give you reasonable default behaviour, you can customise the `CallbackMediaPlayerComponent` if you need to.

The performance of this approach will not be as good as the embedded component, but for most use-cases it will be plenty good enough.